# build path path\spark either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL. Apache Iceberg

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, apache-iceberg

I am trying to launch the dokcer-compose.yaml for Apache Iceberg build found with instructions here:

https://iceberg.apache.org/spark-quickstart/

However when running `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error:

'build path path\spark either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL'

In the compose file I can see this line :

```
    build: spark/
```

So it looks like it is trying to build an image from here?

Why does this not work considering I haven't made any changes?